# ifconfig setting in android app without root

Tags: java, android, linux, ip

I have an Android board, and I connect the board to mobile phone by USB using rndis module.

To set ip for the board, I need to use the command
`ifconfig usb0 x.x.x.x` in minicom, and reset the ip every time if the USB re-plugged.

As a result, I want to write a code for ip auto-setting in my app.
Once the app started, the ip of the board would be set and the app can do other works subsequently.

After some study, the goal of ip setting is reached by the following code:

```
public void ifconfigUsb0IP(String strIP){
              Process process = null;
              DataOutputStream os = null;
      try {
              process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
              os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
              os.writeBytes("ifconfig usb0 "+strIP+"\n");
              os.flush();
      } catch (Exception e) {
              e.getMessage();
      }
```

}

But I don't want the app to have root privilege.
So I `chomd` the ifconfig file in /system/bin to

system system rwxrwxrwx

and then modify the code to the following form:

```
public void ifconfigUsb0IP(String strIP){
              Process process = null;
              DataOutputStream os = null;
      try {
              process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ifconfig usb0 "+strIP);
      } catch (Exception e) {
             e.getMessage();
      }
```

}

But the ip setting doesn't work anymore.

I've tried some ways to write the `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` command, but none can work.

I don't know if this is a syntax error or changing the privilege of ifconfig is just a wrong  idea?

Comment: You can now access the `ifconfig` tool but it is executed with your app permissions which may not be enough to do what it needs to do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I don't quite understand. Can you explain more details for me? Thank you:)

Comment: think of `ifconfig` as a script that executes other commands. And if you execute it it's essentially you that executes all those commands. If one of those commands needs root access `ifconfig` as a whole will fail. Evaluate the output and error streams of the process like shown in http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=3 and see if it shows you why it isn't working.

Comment: I write things like this to check:

`process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");`
`process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ifconfig usb0 "+strIP);`

Still cannot work.
So it seems like not a privilege problem?

Comment: That will not work because the second process is a separate process not running within the `su` context. And `su` is no permanent permission. It's just granted for that process.

Comment: I see. Thank you:)
Unfortunately now the work is in suspended animation due to some problem of the board.
I will share the result if I get solution!